# Auto generate documenttaion in eclipse for javascript

Tags: eclipse, javascript, documentation

I have never used any documentation software or plugin. I am using Eclipse Kepler as code editor for js files.

All files are plain JS files.

Is there any plugin in eclipse where i click button and it auto generates the empty doc tags based on existing code.

It can be any pligin like jsdoc etc. but i want to know how to use that